# Parachain not including all transactions from tx pool into block

Tags: polkadot, parachain, substrate-node, parachain-collator

**Context**

- OriginTrail Parachain Mainnet is pushing significant amount of transactions (175k/day) - with tendency of growth
- Collators are filling blocks up at ~25% of block weight, with a large pending Tx pool
- The pool is gradually growing, and after some time most of transactions are dropped.
- Initial hardware upgrades didn’t contribute to any increase.

[image]

**Goal**

- Increase throughput on OriginTrail Parachain Mainnet by using up more blockspace (target: 50%+ blockweight)

**Code**

- Here is the code: https://github.com/OriginTrail/origintrail-parachain
- Dependencies are on polkadot-v0.9.40.

**Hardware**

Servers have 16vCPU, 8 cores 3.5GHz, 32GB RAM, NVMe disks, NUMA balancing and SMT are disabled. We did not observe any high usage on CPU (~8%) or RAM (~12%).

Our hardware benchmark:

- CPU score: 1.08 GiBs (Min: 1.00 GiBs)
- Memory score: 13.74 GiBs (Min: 14.32 GiBs)
- Disk score (seq. writes): 1.37 GiBs (Min: 450.00 MiBs)
- Disk score (rand. writes): 663.99 MiBs (Min: 200.00 MiBs)

**Tx pool**

You can check current TX pool size here: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fparachain-rpc.origin-trail.network#/explorer/node

Answer (score 0):

> Collators are filling blocks up at ~25% of block weight, with a large pending Tx pool

The worst case of the storage proof usage outputted by the benchmarking is too high currently, probably leading to the effects you are seeing. There is an [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/209) that describe the problem better.

It also depends on how you calculated this 25% usage. I assume you looked only at polkadot-js which is currently ignoring the storage proof usage.

> The pool is gradually growing, and after some time most of transactions are dropped.

All transactions are probably getting rejected at some point, when they are not valid anymore. Why are they pruned from the transaction pool?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, we were looking only at Polkadot-js. Do you have a recommended way to measure block usage, that also takes in account the storage proof usage? How can I check why are they pruned from transaction pool?

Comment: Polkadot js uses the weight for it, but ignores the `storage_proof` size. You would need to check this as well and write some tool on your own. (Maybe already exists somewhere, but should also not be that hard) https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e99007870090e5d09c5526c18d21aa1e1704dac9/substrate/client/transaction-pool/src/revalidation.rs#L100-L108 looking at this log should help on finding out why the tx pool prunes. `txpool=debug` maybe being a good idea in general.

Comment: Hey @NZT, we've been using [evm-tps](https://github.com/paritytech/evm-tps) to stress test networks (it can send EVM txns but also Substrate's extrinsics). We were able to track blocks' weights via pJS using this: https://github.com/paritytech/evm-tps/blob/main/scripts/substrate-tps-server.ts#L323C22-L323C22

Comment: Easiest was to track block weight usage is to subscribe to the storage item `System::BlockWeight`. It does show proof size as well.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions guys. I wanted to return back with latest informations. I had some issues with evm-tps tool, but I created some custom tool that tested basic ERC20 and also heavier EVM transactions that uses 350k of gas on an internally hosted parachain+relay chain. Results are that this tool created enough load that block usage went up to 72% out of 75% which is maximum for regular transactions. I looks like a safe conclusion is that we don't have an issue with proof size. On the other side, we are still confused why we cannot reach this block usage in other environments.

Comment: On the hardware side, we took couple of directions to optimize collators hardware, which also didn't result in much difference: deployed on other cloud providers and optimized servers, compiled binary to target specific CPU architecture, disabled db-cache (made performance worse). If anyone has any other idea, where we should look into for resolving this issue, we would be very grateful

Comment: Also to add info regarding PoV size, we have been observing it, and most of time it is similar to this value: `PoV size { header: 0.7216796875kb, extrinsics: 16.548828125kb, storage_proof: 480.685546875kb }
Compressed PoV size: 403.5458984375kb`. So it is not even close to the limit of 5MB.